# I want to find the difference between two rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two rows fetched from database... The table is something like

```
id | values
------------
1  | speaker
2  | modem
3  | pendrive
```

and another table is something like

```
id | values
------------
1  | speaker
2  | pendrive
```

I want to see like

```
no.| values
------------
1  | modem
```

Comment: You've been here a year, Isn't it about time you had a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)? - SO ***Is NOT a free coding service***

Comment: Look at Array_diff
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do the values in the resulting table correspond to the tables in the database? Where do you want to "see" the result?

Comment: fetch first row in `$array1`, second in `$array2`, then use `array_diff()`

Comment: Although you could do it directly via SQL query, if you still have to do it via PHP I suggest you at least post some code from your attempts, since it looks like you want SO members to code it from scratch for you out of nothing but your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), it will give you exactly what you want:
This is how it works:

```
$newArray= array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn%20$array1%20=%20array(%22speaker%22,%22modem%22,%22pendrive%22);%5Cn%20$array2%20=%20array(%22speaker%22,%22pendrive%22);%5Cn%20$newArray=%20array_diff($array1,%20$array2);%5Cnprint_r($newArray);%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

Comment: I don't think we should encourage bad questions with answer (specially when it's not even a proper one). Wait for OP to refactor it first, if ever.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale so you are basically downvoting me for providing an answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I just made the comment.